# В каком каталоге Sphinx ищет конфиги?

Tags: sphinx, sphinxsearch

Скачиваю архив с последней версии Sphinx c оф. сайта: sphinx-3.4.1-efbcc65-linux-amd64.tar.gz для Ubuntu Server.

Из архива копирую содержимое /bin/* в /usr/bin/. Далее создаю и настраиваю конфиг /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf.

Но при запуске индексатора, Sphinx не видит конфига:

```
# indexer --all --rotate
Sphinx 3.4.1 (commit efbcc65)
Copyright (c) 2001-2021, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

FATAL: no indexes found in config file '(null)'
```

В какой директории по умолчанию Sphinx ищет конфиг?
Пробовал в эти каталоги копировать конфиг - результат тот же:

```
/usr/bin/
/etc/
/etc/sphinx/
```